# Ambiguity between class-name and enumerator-values in C++ natvis

Tags: c++, qt, natvis

I want to create a natvis for `QObject`. There are dynamic properties concepts, which stored in form

```
  QList<QByteArray> propertyNames;
  QVector<QVariant> propertyValues;
```

and I want to group them and visualize as a map(key-value items).

My natvis is pretty simple (for illustration purposes, I replaced all complex logic of getting data from `QList` and `QVector` with `_GetNameAsVoidPtr` and `_GetValueAsVoidPtr`):

```
<Type Name="QObject">
  ...
  <Synthetic Name="dynamic_properties">
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {propertyNames.d-&gt;end - propertyNames.d-&gt;begin} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <CustomListItems>
        <Variable Name="index" InitialValue="0" />
        <Variable Name="size" InitialValue="propertyNames.d-&gt;end - propertyNames.d-&gt;begin" />
        <Loop>
          <Break Condition="index >= size" />
          <Item Name="[{index}] {*reinterpret_cast&lt;const QByteArray*&gt;(_GetNameAsVoidPtr(index))}">
            {*reinterpret_cast&lt;const QVariant*&gt;(_GetValueAsVoidPtr(index))}
          </Item>
          <Exec>++index</Exec>
        </Loop>
      </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Synthetic>
  ...
</Type>
```

I get the following error:

```
Natvis: QObject.natvis(217,21): Error: constant "QByteArray" is not a type name
    Error while evaluating '*reinterpret_cast<const QByteArray*>(_GetNameAsVoidPtr(index))' in the context of type 'Qt5Cored.dll!QObject'.
Natvis: QObject.natvis(217,21): Error: constant "QVariant" is not a type name
    Error while evaluating '*reinterpret_cast<const QVariant*>(_GetValueAsVoidPtr(index))' in the context of type 'Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QObject'.
```

I tried to replace `reinterpret_cast&lt;const QByteArray*&gt;` with `reinterpret_cast&lt;const Qt5Cored.dll::QByteArray*&gt;`, removed `const` and other things - nothing worked. Then I printed these values in VS-Watch window and get the following picture:
[image: TypesEnums]

And here I realised, that Qt has classes: `class QByteArray` and `class QVariant`,
also, it has enum [QMetaType::Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetatype.html#Type-enum) with values `QByteArray` and `QVariant`.
In most places, natvis use types as-is(as you type them in xml), but for some reason, inside `CustomListItems` section, it adds the module name in the front of all types.

So, instead of `QByteArray` and `QVariant`, it treat them as `ModuleName.dll!QByteArray` and `ModuleName.dll!QVariant`. The same for `QString`, for instance. And as you can see on screenshot from Watch window, Visual studio interpet classes with explicit `ModuleName.dll` prefix as enum-values(not classes).

**It there any way to to specify explicitly that `QVariant` is a class, not an enum?**

I tried to add double colons(`::QVariant`) or "class" keyword(`class QVariant`) - does not work :(

I have some ideas how to workaround that issue(if some of them work - i will reply), but first of all, I am curios is there proper way, to tell compiler that it is a class-name?

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Qt Visual Studio Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2022) add-in, it will automatically install qt5.natvis and qt6.natvis. You can also download [qt5.natvis](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/tree/QtVsTools.Package/qt5.natvis.xml) and [qt6.natvis](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/tree/QtVsTools.Package/qt6.natvis.xml), and add them to your project.

As for the error. When your natvis is loaded, QByteArray and QTVariant typs are unknown. You can't use them in expressions.

Comment: I use qt5.natvis, and it's overlight, so I decided to create my own, at least for QObject, QWidget, QLayout(I'm working on it now). 

I am 100% sure that "QByteArray", "QVariant" and other types already known at the moment of natvis reload. If you statement were true, the error had to be something like `Error: identifier "QByteArray" is undefined`. In my case, the error says `constant "QByteArray" is not a type name`. I even provided a screenshot from VS, where you can see, that it knows `QVariant` class, but it thinks that `Qt5Core.dll!QVariant` - is `QMetaType::Type::QVariant` enum value.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I used `QVector::operator[]` for extracting values. Fortunately, this function not optimized and has no side-effects(I am afraid it will not work in Release mode, will test it later).

Tried to do the same for names with `QList::operator[]` and `QList::at()`, but get errors:

> Natvis: QObject.natvis(222,131): Error: no operator "[]" matches these operands
>
> Error while evaluating 'this->extraData->propertyNames[index]' in the context of type 'Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QObjectPrivate'.
> Natvis: QObject.natvis(222,131): Error: Function QList::at has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.
>
> Error while evaluating 'this->extraData->propertyNames.at(index)' in the context of type 'Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QObjectPrivate'.

So, I decided to copy-paste logic from `QByteArray` qt5.natvis and convert it to `const char*`:

```
<Type Name="QObjectPrivate" Inheritable="true">
  ...
  <Synthetic Name="dynamic_properties">
    <DisplayString Condition="this-&gt;extraData == nullptr">{{ size = 0 }}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString>{{ size = {this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyNames.d-&gt;end - this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyNames.d-&gt;begin} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <CustomListItems MaxItemsPerView="25">
        <Variable Name="index" InitialValue="0" />
        <Variable Name="size"
                  InitialValue="this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyNames.d-&gt;end - this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyNames.d-&gt;begin" />
        <Variable Name="p_property_name_byte_array"
                  InitialValue="reinterpret_cast&lt;const char* const*&gt;(this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyNames.d-&gt;array)
                                + this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyNames.d-&gt;begin" />
        <Loop>
          <Break Condition="index >= size" />
          <Item Name="[{index}] {*p_property_name_byte_array +
                      reinterpret_cast&lt;const QTypedArrayData&lt;char&gt;*&gt;(*p_property_name_byte_array)-&gt;offset,sb}">
            this-&gt;extraData-&gt;propertyValues[index]
          </Item>
          <Exec>++index</Exec>
          <Exec>++p_property_name_byte_array</Exec>
        </Loop>
      </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Synthetic>
  ...
</Type>
```

It looks as I expected:

[image: dynamic_properties_visualization]

But my question is still relevant. Is there a way to convince visual_studio/natvis that `QVariant` is a typename, not a `QMetaType::Type::QVariant`.